# C# powerpoint interop multiple slide shows

Tags: c#, interop, slideshow, powerpoint

I have a server that exports powerpoints to a network folder (I know microsoft does not recommend it, so please spare me those)

My application should be used to display powerpoints on large TVs, and thus I want to have a continious flow of powerpoints slide shows (no flickering).
I have an event (FileSystemWatcher) that checks whenever a new file is created on that folder. When it is, it opens with powerpoint and start the slide show.

Problem is if I start slide show without considering the old, it works nicely, a short hiccup but no flickering. However then I have loads of powerpoint instances open.

I tried to start slide show, and close old instances, but when I do, the new slide show is closed/exited too.

Any suggestions?

The code for the working, but not very memory friendly....

```
PPT.Application oPpt = new PPT.Application();
PPT.Presentations oPresSet = oPpt.Presentations;
PPT.Presentation oPres = oPresSet.Open(e.FullPath, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
PPT.Slides oSlides = oPres.Slides;
PPT.SlideShowSettings objSSS = oPres.SlideShowSettings;

objSSS.Run();
```

Comment: I'd give the problem another look.  You don't have multiple instances of PowerPoint running, at least not under normal circumstances.  PowerPoint won't permit it.  Try creating multiple references, a la oPres1 and oPres2.  After opening oPres2 and putting it in slide show view, call .Close on oPres1 that was open before.  Then open a new presentation as oPres1, launch it in slide show view, call .Close on oPres2 and so on.

Comment: Hi, sorry about instances, but i meant multiple windows. I tried that, but when you close oPres2, then it exits oPres1's slide show

Comment: You can try this by opening two powerpoints, start slideshow on presentation1, then start slideshow on presentation2 and close presentation1. It will exit the slideshow...

Comment: Is PowerPoint closing or crashing?  I just tried this from w/in PPT: in one presentation I added VBA to open another presentation, then put it in slide show view, then open a third presentation and put IT in slide show view, then finally close the second presentation, the first one I had in slide show view.  Reliably crashes PPT on that last step.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution (for powerpoint 2010)
First start slide show for presentation 1, then I retrieve the slideshowview for it. 
Start slide show for presentation 2, then close slide show for presentation 1 with slideshowview, then close presentation for presentation 1.

In Code (continuing on my code from above)

```
objSSS.Run();
PPT.SlideShowView oSlideView = oPres.SlideShowWindow.View;


if (oldPPTPres != null && oldPPTView != null)
{
     oldPPTView.Exit();

     oldPPTPres.Close();
}

oldPPTView = oSlideView;
oldPPTPres = oPres;
```